# error: git-submodule died of signal 11

Tags: macos, command-line, git, perl, macos-highsierra

FML edit:
So.....
long story short, it was a function I had in my bashrc profile...
test() { npm run test $1 $2 $3 $4 ;}; export -f test

But!

How did I track this down, you might ask?

Well, after some digging with iosnoop, I looked up why iosnoop was giving `??`'s in paths, which led me to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191708/why-iosnoop-io-snooping-files-on-disk-returns-paths-with-question-marks

which supplied me with this magic command
`sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'`

That command gives you only the io, read's actually, apparently executes too I believe, of every `syscall::open*:entry`. I wasn't sure how to single out git, but the process name is quite easily identifiable in the output, so used that command to compare the IO of `sudo git submodule` and `git submodule`

And the results were as follows:

```
# git submodule
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  2    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x10b832652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git .
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/local/etc/gitconfig
  0    171                       open:entry sh /dev/dtracehelper
  4    171                       open:entry sh /dev/tty
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-submodule
  2    171                       open:entry basename /dev/dtracehelper
  4    171                       open:entry sed /dev/dtracehelper
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  1    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  1    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  1    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  1    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  2    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  4    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  4    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  4    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x10f47f652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  0    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-i18n
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry ReportCrash /bin
```

```
sudo git submodule
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  2    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  2    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry git /etc/master.passwd
  4    171                       open:entry git /dev/autofs_nowait
  4    171                       open:entry git /var/root/.CFUserTextEncoding
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /etc/master.passwd
  4    171                       open:entry git /dev/autofs_nowait
  4    171                       open:entry git /var/root/.CFUserTextEncoding
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x107dd7652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git .
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/local/etc/gitconfig
  0    171                       open:entry sh /dev/dtracehelper
  4    171                       open:entry sh /dev/tty
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh .
  4    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-submodule
  4    171                       open:entry basename /dev/dtracehelper
  2    171                       open:entry sed /dev/dtracehelper
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  4    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  2    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  0    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x10af1c652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  2    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-i18n
  2    171                       open:entry sh /dev/null
  2    171                       open:entry sh /opt/local/bin/gettext.sh
  0    171                       open:entry sh /dev/null
  0    171                       open:entry sh /dev/null
  4    171                       open:entry basename /dev/dtracehelper
  2    171                       open:entry sed /dev/dtracehelper
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  2    171                       open:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin/gettext
  2    171                       open:entry gettext /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry gettext /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry gettext /dev/dtracehelper
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin/envsubst
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /opt/local/share/locale/locale.alias
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /dev/dtracehelper
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin/envsubst
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /dev/dtracehelper
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  2    171                       open:entry uname /dev/dtracehelper
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  0    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x101b2d652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git .
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/share/locale/locale.alias
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
```

This let me compare line by line the IOps of each command, leading to the very clear branch point of the command
`2    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-i18n`

so I nano'd into ??/git-sh-i18n and added some `echo "debug n"` lines to figure out where the segfault was occuring

It turned out it was occuring at a `test -z` line, and the reason it didn't crash with `sudo git submodule` is because sudo opens a new shell.

so...

yeah.... for future reference.......... this is the only google search result for error: git-submodule died of signal 11

But hey, I didn't need those 10 hours of lifetime

Edit:
So I found out that running `sudo git submodule` works, so it's a permission error, I did a dtruss trace which you can read here, https://pastebin.com/k1qNCsTY

But I have no idea how dtruss works so I can't figure out which fs object is being accesses with the wrong permissions, it looks like it tries to access `1477/0x3e98:  write_nocancel(0x1, "/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core\n\b\0", 0x2E)        = 46 0` right before the error `1471/0x3e8b:  write_nocancel(0x2, "error: git-submodule died of signal 11\n\0", 0x27)      = 39 0` is thrown, but I don't know what write_nocancel means,

It turns out that git-submodule resides inside `libexec/git-core` and the permissions are

`lopu@lopu-pro:~/tmp/test2$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/ | grep submodule
-rwxr-xr-x   1 lopu  admin    23373 25 Feb 03:31 git-submodule`

on my computer

End edit.

I've got a super weird problem occurring as of yesterday.

Software specs are

OS: OS X 10.13.4

Git: 2.21.0

Node: 10.15.3

npm: 6.4.1

perl: 5.18.2

What I'm running into is an issue where running `git submodule update` anywhere in my system returns the error `error: git-submodule died of signal 11`

I found out about this error when I tried to install an npm module from a git repository url

for example

```
mkdir test ; cd test ; npm init -y
npm i lopugit/test# https://github.com/lopugit/test if you want to take a look, literally an empty npm package
```

for me, this brings up

```
lopu@lopu-pro:~/tmp/test2$ npm i lopugit/test
npm ERR! code 139
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git submodule update -q --init --recursive
npm ERR! error: git-submodule died of signal 11
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lopu/.npm/_logs/2019-03-31T10_48_41_525Z-debug.log
```

```
# /Users/lopu/.npm/_logs/2019-03-31T10_48_41_525Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/lopu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/lopu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'lopugit/test' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose npm-session 24a6679416e47473
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for github:lopugit/test Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git submodule update -q --init --recursive
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error: git-submodule died of signal 11
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2532ms
10 verbose stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git submodule update -q --init --recursive
10 verbose stack error: git-submodule died of signal 11
10 verbose stack
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
10 verbose stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
10 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
10 verbose stack     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:597:12)
11 verbose cwd /Users/lopu/tmp/test2
12 verbose Darwin 17.5.0
13 verbose argv "/Users/lopu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node" "/Users/lopu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm" "i" "lopugit/test"
14 verbose node v10.15.3
15 verbose npm  v6.4.1
16 error code 139
17 error Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git submodule update -q --init --recursive
17 error error: git-submodule died of signal 11
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I thought maybe it was perl, but on osx you can't update perl, I looked into activeperl, but that would mean changing the perl version that git uses.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

I've tried fixing perl with this: 
`sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->notest(install => CPAN::Shell->r)'`

and updating xcode via the app store.

The thing that makes me think it's a perl issue is that when I was looking into upgrading perl, I tried installing brewperl, which led me to run this command after installing it

```
brewperl install-5.18.1
```

getting this error log file

```
Auto-guessed '5.18.1'
patching Configure
patching ext/Errno/Errno_pm.PL
sh: line 1:  2709 Segmentation fault: 11  sh Configure -de '-Dprefix=/Users/lopu/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1' '-A'eval:scriptdir=/Users/lopu/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin''
##### Brew Failed #####
```

I also did a dtruss trace and got this

https://pastebin.com/k1qNCsTY

breaches the 30000 superuser character limit

holy shit running as sudo makes it work, must be a permission issue.....

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it was the following function I had in my `.bashrc` profile:

```
test() { npm run test $1 $2 $3 $4 ;}; export -f test
```

But!

How did I track this down, you might ask?

Well, after some digging with iosnoop, I looked up why iosnoop was giving `??`'s in paths, which led me to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191708/why-iosnoop-io-snooping-files-on-disk-returns-paths-with-question-marks

which supplied me with this magic command
`sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'`

That command gives you only the io, read's actually, apparently executes too I believe, of every `syscall::open*:entry`. I wasn't sure how to single out git, but the process name is quite easily identifiable in the output, so used that command to compare the IO of `sudo git submodule` and `git submodule`

And the results were as follows:

```
# git submodule
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  2    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x10b832652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git .
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/local/etc/gitconfig
  0    171                       open:entry sh /dev/dtracehelper
  4    171                       open:entry sh /dev/tty
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-submodule
  2    171                       open:entry basename /dev/dtracehelper
  4    171                       open:entry sed /dev/dtracehelper
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  1    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  1    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  1    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  1    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  2    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  4    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  4    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  4    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x10f47f652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  0    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-i18n
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry ReportCrash /bin
```

```
sudo git submodule
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  2    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  2    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry git /etc/master.passwd
  4    171                       open:entry git /dev/autofs_nowait
  4    171                       open:entry git /var/root/.CFUserTextEncoding
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /etc/master.passwd
  4    171                       open:entry git /dev/autofs_nowait
  4    171                       open:entry git /var/root/.CFUserTextEncoding
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x107dd7652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git .
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/local/etc/gitconfig
  0    171                       open:entry sh /dev/dtracehelper
  4    171                       open:entry sh /dev/tty
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry sh .
  4    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-submodule
  4    171                       open:entry basename /dev/dtracehelper
  2    171                       open:entry sed /dev/dtracehelper
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  4    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  2    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  0    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x10af1c652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  2    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-i18n
  2    171                       open:entry sh /dev/null
  2    171                       open:entry sh /opt/local/bin/gettext.sh
  0    171                       open:entry sh /dev/null
  0    171                       open:entry sh /dev/null
  4    171                       open:entry basename /dev/dtracehelper
  2    171                       open:entry sed /dev/dtracehelper
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry sed /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  2    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  2    171                       open:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin/gettext
  2    171                       open:entry gettext /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry gettext /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  2    171                       open:entry gettext /dev/dtracehelper
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin/envsubst
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry gettext /opt/local/share/locale/locale.alias
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  4    171                       open:entry gettext /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /dev/dtracehelper
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  4    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /opt/local/bin/envsubst
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  6    171                       open:entry envsubst /dev/dtracehelper
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  6    957              open_nocancel:entry envsubst /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  2    171                       open:entry uname /dev/dtracehelper
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry uname /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin
  0    171                       open:entry taskgated /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  0    171                       open:entry git /dev/dtracehelper
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 171: syscall::open:entry): invalid address (0x101b2d652) in action #2 at DIF offset 12
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_TIME
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git .
  0    957              open_nocancel:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/share/locale/locale.alias
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
  0    171                       open:entry git /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
```

This let me compare line by line the IOps of each command, leading to the very clear branch point of the command
`2    171                       open:entry sh /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-sh-i18n`

so I nano'd into ??/git-sh-i18n and added some `echo "debug n"` lines to figure out where the segfault was occuring

It turned out it was occuring at a `test -z` line, and the reason it didn't crash with `sudo git submodule` is because sudo opens a new shell.

so...

yeah.... for future reference.......... this is the only google search result for error: git-submodule died of signal 11

But hey, I didn't need those 10 hours of lifetime